# What is the reverse operation of bitwise AND?

Tags: java, jmf, j#

How can I get `a` from `b` and `c`? What would be the reverse operation?

Here is the code:

```
class  s
{
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {

        int a = 20;

        int b = 5;

        int c = 0;

        c = (a & b) ;

        System.out.println(c);

        int d = (c & b);

        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. If a bit in `c` is 0 and the corresponding bit in `b` is 0, it's impossible to know whether the corresponding bit in `a` was 0 or 1. By a similar argument, bitwise OR (the `|` operator) is also irreversible. On the other hand, bitwise XOR (the `^` operator) *is* reversible.

Comment: As a concrete example, if for 1-bit numbers, `c` is 1 and `a` is 1, then `b` could be either 0 or 1.  More generally, when `c == a`, the fact that `c = a | b` gives you *no* information about `b` : `P(b == n ┃ ((a == c && (c == a | b))) == P(b == n)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the truth table of the `and` logical operation, you can see that it contains three falses and one true. Therefore it can't be reversed.

Only `equals` and `xor` have balanced truth tables, and they are the two reversible boolean operators.