# Time encoded in PHP using Bitwise operators. How do I decode a Result?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

Time encoded in PHP using Bitwise Or (inclusive or) and Shift left [<<]  operator. How do I decode a Result to get Back  Year, TotalDays, totalSeconds?

```
$Year=17;   // means 2017
$TotalDays=223;
$totalSeconds=5435;

$Result = ( (intval($Year) << 26) | (intval($TotalDays) << 17) | intval($totalSeconds));
```

The orignal Algorithm that is encoding hermes time is given below
  The orignal Algorithm that is encoding hermes time is given below

```
unsigned int Gps_DateTimeEncode(short Hours,short Minutes,short Seconds,short Year,short Month, short Days)
{
  unsigned int Result;
  int Months[12]= {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
  int TotalSeconds = (Hours *3600) + (Minutes * 60) + Seconds;
  int TotalDays=0,i;
  if(Year%4==0)  Months[1]=29;

  for(i=0;i<Month-1;i++)
  {
    TotalDays+=Months[i];
  }
  TotalDays+=Days;
  Result =  ((Year) << 26) | (TotalDays << 17) | (TotalSeconds) ;
  return Result;                                                    
}
```

Comment: Why is it encoded this way? Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Actually It is encoded by a Device Hermes to save a Space .Result is a Formated 4 byte Date Time Representation.

Comment: I have Researched, but the world says  Or  bitwise operator is irreversible . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330520/what-is-the-reverse-operation-of-bitwise-and

Comment: The First 6 bits is for year , Next 9 bits is for totaldays and the remaining is for totalSeconds.

Comment: OK I wrote an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Takes an encoded date and returns a \stdClass object with 'year', 'days'
 * and 'seconds' properties decoded
 * @param int $encoded Encoded date
 * @return \stdClass
 */
function decodeHermesTime($encoded){

    $obj = new \stdClass();

    // right-shift 26 spots to get raw year
    $obj->year = $encoded >> 26;

    // subtract year bits from $encoded to get daysAndSecondsBits
    $daysAndSecondsBits = $encoded - ($obj->year << 26);

    // right-shift 17 times to get days
    $obj->days = $daysAndSecondsBits >> 17;

    // subtract days bits from $daysAndSecondsBits to have raw seconds
    $obj->seconds = $daysAndSecondsBits - ($obj->days << 17);

    return $obj;
}

// usage:
$Result = 17 << 26 | 223 << 17 | 5435;
$r = decodeHermesTime($Result);
echo "Year: $r->year, Days: $r->days, Seconds: $r->seconds";
// Year: 17, Days: 223, Seconds: 5435
```

[**Live Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc93057905971c8f09c50b87138e12ab10cd6433)

Comment: $encoded=1501158172    This is the encoded time that is coming from hermes device but  when I decode through your code the result is  Year: 22, Days: 188, Seconds: 121628. It is impossible for year to be 22.so may be  there is an error  in Hermes Encode Algo.

Comment: I have Added orignal encoding function [Gps_DateTimeEncode] that is generating 1501158172 in the above section and I am decoding the same [1501158172] with your decodeHermesTime funcation .Thanks

Comment: @AliRaza I don't understand the question. Why do you think year 22 is impossible?

Comment: The Hermes  devices are sending live data so it must be 17 [2017]

Comment: If I get Hours From Seconds $hours = floor($obj->seconds / 3600); it gives me 33 hour which is immposible. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3956067849adab49dfbe5f2d56d349e819c74128

Comment: @AliRaza Sure it's possible. If the original `Gps_DateTimeEncode` function is called with 33 as the `Hours` parameter, then the decoder will yield a number of seconds that corresponds to at least 33hrs.  This is because if you look at the code for that function, `TotalSeconds` is the sum of all hours, minutes and seconds that were input.